# Fetch predefined account in hardhat and deploy contract from that address

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, contract-deployment, hardhat

I'm trying to deploy a smart contract from my frontend. Using the hardhat account which I defined in `hardhat.config.js` using the private key, and setting an argument (`raffleOwner`) as the address of the metamask. So that later on in my smart contract I can do actions which only the `raffleOwner` or `raffleAdmin` will have access to.

But for now I'm just looking on how to get this deployed from the frontend. I'm using nuxt, but any example really helps.

Here's my hardhat.config.js

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

const ALCHEMY_API_KEY = "";
const GOERLI_PRIVATE_KEY = "";

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.0",
  networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: `https://eth-goerli.alchemyapi.io/v2/${ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`,
      accounts: [GOERLI_PRIVATE_KEY]
    }
  }
};
```